# Caret styling in contenteditable div without text

Tags: html, css, contenteditable, caret

How do you style the caret for a contenteditable div when there is no text in the div.

Before text is entered: 
[image]

After text is entered: 
[image]

Notice how the caret on the before shot is up against the top of div, not vertically-centered like it is once text is entered. I know you can prepopulate the div with `<br>` before and it fixes it but I'm hoping there is a better solution. This is a minor thing that has been bugging me for a while.

Comment: Give us a fiddle demonstrating the problem.  So we can fiddle with it.  http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, doing a simple example helped me see the problem.

Comment: Reduced test case ftw.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, you can't use `line-height`. You need to use `padding`. Here's the difference http://jsfiddle.net/frcso1n9/1/

HTML

```
<div class="lineheight">
    <div contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div contenteditable="true">with text</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="padding">
    <div contenteditable="true"></div>
    <div contenteditable="true">with text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.lineheight div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.padding div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```